# Propagation of Error for Sum of Reciprocals

Tags: calculus, error-propagation

Given a set of $n$ complex numbers $a_i$ and error magnitude $\epsilon_i$ with $|a_i| > \epsilon_i$. We define the error disk $D(\epsilon_i) = \{ z \mid |z| \leq \epsilon_i\}$. We have the set

$$
F = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + D(\epsilon_i)}
$$
Now, I would like to find a minimum $\delta$ such that
$$
G = D(\delta) + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}
$$
and $F \subset G$. Sorry, for the awkward notation, I guess there is a much better to conceptualize this. Please enlighten me.